# Files downloaded into external hard drive use up space in / on Ubuntu

Tags: external-hdd

I have a WD 2TB My Passport Portable External Hard Drive mounted on my Raspberry Pi 4 which I use to store files. I am currently using a Python script to download files locally into the external hard drive, but these are also using up space in my Raspberry. Oddly, I cannot find the files in the Raspberry.

Ubuntu 22.04 is installed in my Raspberry, using a 30GB SSD card. The command `df -h` gives the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           380M  3,7M  376M   1% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2   29G   17G   11G  62% /
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M  125M  128M  50% /boot/firmware
tmpfs           379M   88K  379M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       1,9T  327G  1,6T  18% /home/tomas/wdpassport
```

When I start downloading files into the external hard drive, they start using space in `/dev/mmcblk0p2`. They weird things is that this also happens when I connect the hard drive to my laptop (also with Ubuntu 22.04). I have tried mounting it on different directories as well, but this doesn't help. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: It is unclear what kind of a script you are using, why do you need a script to download to an external drive, how do you know that "they start using space in /dev/mmcblk0p2"?

Comment: The script downloads FITS files using `astropy.table` with URLs. This runs on my laptop without problems. The issue comes when I download the files on my external hard drive. I know that the files are using space in my Raspberry because I run the command `df -h` again after downloading several files.

Comment: I have no idea what "FITS files" or "astropy.table" are. Probably the script writes to a wrong place. We can't tell anything without the script.

Comment: The FITS format is commonly used for astronomical images (not relevant as this also happens with other files such as png or jpg). The script is writing in the correct place as I can find the files in my external hard drive, where they should be. However, these are also using space in my Raspberry.

Comment: If they are "also using space" then the script writes to both drives.

Comment: That is the odd part. I know the files are only downloaded in the path given as I have tried this on different computers. Also, the downloaded files are only found in the external hard drive but cannot be found in the Raspberry.

Comment: It might be possible that the script is downloading the file(s) to the RPi then moving it/them to the external keeping the deleted file(s) open wasting space on the RPi.  You might want to see https://serverfault.com/questions/232525/df-in-linux-not-showing-correct-free-space-after-file-removal

Comment: Thanks. I have tried looking for deleted files, but I don't think this is the problem. The output of `lsof +L1` is `pipewire  1020 tomas   33u   REG    0,1     2312     0 2053 /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)`, `pulseaudi 1796 tomas    6u   REG    0,1 67108864     0 2056 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the source of the used space. The `astropy` package saves the cache in a hidden directory (`/home/tomas/.astropy/cache` in my case). That is why I wasn't finding it. I used the `clear_download_cache()` function of the package to clear the content and I got back the used space. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice find!  Don't forget to mark you answer as correct.  This can help others that might be experiencing the same thing.  :)